# Proper way to Declare and Search List in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog. Is it possible to "declare" a list as a fact in Prolog, and then access it easily? I'm working on a family-tree type problem. To start, I would like to declare a bunch of males as belonging to a list of males. I then would like to be able to query if a particular person is a male. Here is the code I've written so far:

```
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Facts:

males([john, joseph, aaron, peter, paul, mark, ben, adam, daniel]).


% ------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Rules:

% Member of a List
member(X, [X|_]).
member(X, [_|T]) :- member(X, T).

male(X) :- member(X, males).
```

However, my output is not as expected:

```
21 ?- male(john).
```

false.

I know my member() rules are working, since I can produce the following result:

```
23 ?- member(john, [peter, paul, john]).
```

true

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not how Prolog works. `males` isn't a function that returns the list. It's a fact that you declared, and it needs to be queried: `male(X).` query will return `X = [john, joseph, aaron, peter, paul, mark, ben, adam, daniel]`. But see Boris' answer for a more proper way to assert these kinds of facts.

Answer (score 1):

The usual proper way to do this in Prolog would be to declare your list as a table of facts:

```
male(john).
male(joseph).
% etc
```

If you do it like this, you have already defined your `male/1` and can query it either like this:

```
?- male(joseph).
true.
```

Or like this:

```
?- male(M).
M = john ;
M = joseph ;
% etc
```

You can start with Prolog by reading through the [first chapter of "Learn Prolog Now!"](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse1). Its first example is exactly the same as your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in prolog but I know a solution to this (could be not the only one)

male(X) :- males(Y), member(X, Y)

The way I understand it is that predicates doesn't return variables, they assign values to the parameters given, so Y now have been assigned the array of males and now you can look for X in Y

Comment: Thank you for clarifying how predicates work. That was my problem. Your solution works, of course. Thanks!